# body overflow:visible on pop up close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is JS function to show pop up contact form:

```
function check_empty(){
if(document.getElementById('name').value == "" 
|| document.getElementById('email').value == "" 
||document.getElementById('msg').value == "" ){
alert ("Fill All Fields !");
}
    else {  
    document.getElementById('form').submit();  
    alert ("Form submitted successfully...");
    }
}

//function to display Popup
function div_show(){ 
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

//function to check target element
function check(e){ 
var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 

var obj = document.getElementById('abc'); 
var obj2 = document.getElementById('popup'); 
checkParent(target)?obj.style.display='none':null; 
target==obj2?obj.style.display='block':null; 
} 


//function to check parent node and return result accordingly
function checkParent(t){ 
    while(t.parentNode){ 
        if(t==document.getElementById('abc'))
            { 
                return false 
            }
        else if(t==document.getElementById('close'))
            {
                return true

            } 
        t=t.parentNode 

    } 
    return true 

}
```

When popup load `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` deactivate overflow. Now i want to set `document.body.style.overflow = "visible";` on close button click (when i close pop up). Close button is defined in html for as : `<img src="images/3.png" id="close"/>` Is it possible ? Here is full html form:

```
 <form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
        <img src="images/3.png" id="close"/>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2><hr/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>

        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>

        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="msg"></textarea>

        <a id="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()">Send</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: Just add an onclick event to the image and you're done !

Comment: i tried `<img src="images/3.png" id="close" onclick ="overflow visible"/>`  but it is not workong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<img src="images/3.png" id="close" onclick="myFunction()">
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "visible";
}
```